# how to access non public content in the java external libraries

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a new button creation class that takes dimensions as well as text and icons as arguments. To do it I'm using the JButton class as reference and adding my own stuff. The problem is that in the writeObject method, which seems to be needed to get the button to add, the .setWriteObjCounter says it is only accessible from within the same package. Does anyone know how to get access to it? (Other than putting it in the package, because I can't do that)

```
import javax.accessibility.Accessible;
import javax.accessibility.AccessibleContext;
import javax.accessibility.AccessibleRole;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.ButtonUI;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
public class JMButton extends AbstractButton implements Accessible {
  private static final String uiClassID = "JMButtonUI";
  //constructors for different inputs 
  public JMButton() {
    this(null, null, 0, 0);
  }
  public JMButton(String text) {
    this(text, null, 0, 0);
  }
  public JMButton(Icon icon) {
    this(null, icon, 0, 0);
  }
  public JMButton(String text, Icon icon) {
    this(text, icon, 0, 0);
  }
  public JMButton(String text, int width, int height) {
    this(text, null, width, height);
  }
  public JMButton(Icon icon, int width, int height) {
    this(null, icon, width, height);
  }
  public JMButton(int width, int heigth) {
    this(null, null, width, heigth);
  }
  public JMButton(Action a) {
    this();
    setAction(a);
  }
  public JMButton(String text, Icon icon, int width, int height) {
    setModel(new DefaultButtonModel());
    init(text, icon);
    if (width == 0) {
      FontMetrics fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
      int buttonWidth = fontMetrics.stringWidth(text);
      setSize(buttonWidth + 40, 40);
    } else {
      setSize(width, height);
    }
  }
  //pulled from other button classes for functionality
  public void updateUI() {
    setUI((ButtonUI) UIManager.getUI(this));
  }
  public String getUIClassID() {
    return uiClassID;
  }
  //PROBLEM!!
  private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
    s.defaultWriteObject();
    if (getUIClassID().equals(uiClassID)) {
      byte count = JComponent.getWriteObjCounter(this);
      JComponent.setWriteObjCounter(this, --count);
      if (count == 0 && ui != null) {
        ui.installUI(this);
      }
    }
  }
  public AccessibleContext getAccessibleContext() {
    if (accessibleContext == null) {
      accessibleContext = new AccessibleJButton();
    }
    return accessibleContext;
  }
  protected class AccessibleJButton extends AccessibleAbstractButton {
    public AccessibleRole getAccessibleRole() {
      return AccessibleRole.PUSH_BUTTON;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's usually what I recommend in situations like this.  Start by asking yourself "Why would I ever want to do this?"

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There is a reason that it is marked package protected. It's because it's not meant to be used by anyone outside the package. You *can* do this via reflection, but I would first ask myself *why* I am doing this and to see if there is another way I can achieve what I want to do. Overriding visibility via reflection is a sign that something is wrong in your design, and is required only in the rarest of cases.

Comment: I may just be being ignorant here, but is there any reason why he can't just extend JButton?

Comment: yes there is, I need the packet permissions to access the methods

Comment: You don't need to do that. You can just extend JButton and all the writeObjects shenanegans will be done for you by the internals of Swing. You don't have to manually invoke it or even know that it's there.

Comment: @javapirate think about it. Do you think Swing was designed in such a way so that developers said to themselves: "you can't extend our code unless you use our package name". If a method in an API is private, it is not a part of the api and you should not try to call it using stupid tricks like using the same package name, or using reflection to obtain the method instance. If you want to extend JButton functionality, extend JButton. If you want to extend AbstractButton functionality, extend AbstractButton. In either cases you wouldn't have to do anything with the writeObject method.

Comment: @baba Please review your comments. Are you addressing the right person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Work Around:**

Create the same package structure of the class you are extending in your project and add your class to it.
So you will have in your project a package **javax.swing**

```
package javax.swing;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import javax.accessibility.Accessible;

public class JMButton extends AbstractButton implements Accessible {
    private static final String uiClassID = "JMButtonUI";

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        s.defaultWriteObject();
        if (getUIClassID().equals(uiClassID)) {
            byte count = JComponent.getWriteObjCounter(this);
            JComponent.setWriteObjCounter(this, --count);
            if (count == 0 && ui != null) {
                ui.installUI(this);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not going to be the only one using it, my friends will too so I really need to leave the external libraries alone, plus you cant actualy edit the external libraries

Comment: you wont change anything in the external library, the only thing in this case is that the class will need to be at this specific package structure in your project

Comment: Thanks!! really helpful!!! I didn't quite get what you meant the first time, sorry!

Comment: that is ok... please point me up if this answer solved your problem

Comment: That is madness, just extend the JButton class, don't let some workaround define your project structure.

Comment: @baba first understand the question before point me down, he needs to invoke a method with package permission, only extending doesn't allow it.

Comment: @fmodods He doesen't need to invoke methods with package permission, he is using JButton as a "reference" and adding his own stuff. How is that not suitable for using inheritance? A proper way to reuse a class and extend its functionality ...surprise, is by EXTENDING the class.

Comment: @baba yes, he is adding his own stuff but he also needs to invoke a package method which is "JComponent.setWriteObjCounter(this, --count);", try to invoke this method without adding the class to the package javax.swing. Btw he already extends the javax.swing.AbstractButton, please read the code before commenting based only in the question.

Comment: I read the code. If he just extended JButton, and not AbstractButton, then everything else would be fine. No need to call the setWriteObjectCounter and to make weird package tricks. Simplicity is always better! If you want to use JButton as a friggin reference, extend the frigging JButton, not the friggin AbstractButton, then override the methods of JButton that you don't like. Obviously Swing's APi was designed so the setWriteObjCounter method is package private, then it is a big mistake to try to call it manually. Downvote stays cause you are giving harmful advice.

Comment: I made it clear that was a work around which worked for him... if you had posted your solution, we wouldn't need to waste our time into this "argument"